# Missing required key 'Key' in params deleteObject aws

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello i have want to delete an image from aws so i am using the function deleteObject but i got the error Missing required key 'Key' in params deleteObject aws and many other errors , this is my code

```
 export function deleteImage(fileName, bucketName) {
          const params = {
                    Bucket: bucketName, 
                    key: `${bucketName}/${fileName}`
           }; 
            return s3Instance.deleteObject(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else  console.log(data);   
         });
      }
```

what is confusing me that i have other functions like getFile and copyObject with exactly the same syntax  and same everything and they work fine
ps: i used filename as a key in the beginning but i found when searching that the key should be the full path to the image but even like this didn't work, so any help ?

Comment: It should be Key not key in the params object.

Comment: key should be capital letter, not sure if bucket/filename is actual key, verify in s3

Comment: Typically, when you supply an object key to an AWS SDK, it should not include the bucket name and it should not be a URI such as `s3:://bucket/mykey`. Also, you're mistaken about your use of `getFile` and `copyObject`. There is no `getFile` in the AWS SDK for S3 and `copyObject`, like `deleteObject`, requires `Key` with a capital `K`.

Comment: Also after capitalization fix the value of Key should not include the bucket name.